# update values if duplicate in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've got a problem with checking for duplicate values in `JTable`. User enters a 'product code' and an 'amount', app is looking for the item name using 'product code' and adds to the table values. I want to check for duplicates in `JTable`, but I don't know how to do it. I want the user to choose for example code: 55 and amount 3, then it's added to `JTable` but if the user enters again 55 and amount 5, it is adding another row, what I want is to update the amount 3 + 5.

That's what I did so far.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class StockBasket extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JTable table;
    private Vector rows, columns;
    private DefaultTableModel tabModel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JButton addBtn, deleteBtn;
    private JPanel mainPanel, buttonPanel;
    private String productName;
    private String spinnerAmount;
    private int quantityDbInt;
    private int amountInt;
public StockBasket() {
    rows = new Vector();
    columns = new Vector();
    String[] columnNames = { "Amount to update", "Product name",
            "Total in stock after update" };
    addColumns(columnNames);

    tabModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tabModel.setDataVector(rows, columns);

    table = new JTable(tabModel);
    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);// ScrollPane
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 200));

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    addBtn = new JButton("ADD TO UPDATE");
    deleteBtn = new JButton("DELETE");
    deleteBtn.setEnabled(false);

    buttonPanel.add(addBtn);
    buttonPanel.add(deleteBtn);

    addBtn.addActionListener(this);
    deleteBtn.addActionListener(this);

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setSize(450, 300);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add("Center", scrollPane);
    mainPanel.add("North", buttonPanel);
    add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent source) {
    if (source.getSource() == (JButton) addBtn) {
        addBtnChecks();
    } else if (source.getSource() == (JButton) deleteBtn) {
        deleteRow(table.getSelectedRow());
    }
}

private void addBtnChecks() {
    productName = new MyDatabase(3).getName();
    amountInt = Integer.parseInt(UpdateStock.getAmount().getValue()
            .toString());
    if (new MyDatabase(3).getQuantity() == null) {
        // if the answer from db is null do not parseInt
    } else {
        quantityDbInt = Integer.parseInt(new MyDatabase(3).getQuantity());
    }
    if (productName == null) {
        UpdateStock.getErrorMsg().setText("Enter correct code");

    } else if (amountInt == 0) {
        UpdateStock.getErrorMsg().setText("Please enter correct amount");

    } else {
        addRow();
        UpdateStock.getAmount().setValue(0);
        UpdateStock.getStockNo().setText("");
        UpdateStock.getErrorMsg().setText("");
        deleteBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void addColumns(String[] colName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < colName.length; i++)
        columns.addElement(colName[i]);
}

private void addRow() {
    Vector r = new Vector();
    r = createNewElement();
    rows.addElement(r);
    table.addNotify();
}

private Vector createNewElement() {
    Vector t = new Vector();
    spinnerAmount = UpdateStock.getAmount().getValue().toString();
    int spinnerAmountInt = Integer.parseInt(spinnerAmount);
    // read product name from database
    productName = new MyDatabase(3).getName();
    // itemsInStock - get value from db and add amount added by user
    int itemsInStock = quantityDbInt + spinnerAmountInt;
    t.addElement(spinnerAmount);
    t.addElement(productName);
    t.addElement(itemsInStock);
    return t;
}

private void deleteRow(int index) {
    // makes the first row always selected
    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
    int size = tabModel.getRowCount();
    if (size == 1) { // can't delete when no items
        deleteBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (index != -1) { // At least one Row in Table
        rows.removeElementAt(index);
        table.addNotify();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: +1 nice question, I think that about Iterating inside DefaultTableModel......., update all shadowed classes with value stored in local variable

Comment: be sure you read and understand the tutorial chapter on JTable (you are doing the update completely wrong) Calling random api is never an option (f.i. addNotify ... tsee). Unrelated: a) don't fiddle with sizing hints ever (that is don't call setXXSize) b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for hints, I don't know where I'm not stacked to the Java naming conventions. Can u show me how to do update in a good way? thanks

Comment: `product code` is nowhere in your JTable column..!!!!

Comment: @VishalK is called `productName` and the other class is responsible to do this operation. sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  The best ones involve a clean separation between the data model (a list of stocks with amounts) and the table model (an adapter to express that in a way JTable understands).

Start with a `List<StockHolding>` where `StockHolding` is a super-simple class you make to hold the data for one row.

```
public class StockHolding {
  private String product;
  private int quantity;
}
```

(add in the constructor and getProduct/getQuantity)

Now when you enter a new product+amount...

```
addRequest(String product, int amount) {
  StockHolding holding = findInList(product, myList);
  if (holding == null) {
    myList.add(new StockHolding(product, amount));
  } else {
    holding.setQuantity(amount+holding.getQuantity());
  }
```

The key to making this work is to express your table model in terms of this list.  `getRowCount()` returns `myList.size()` and the cell values are `getValue(myList.get(rowNum), columnNum)` where `getValue()` maps the column number to product or amount respectively.

This important lesson here is that isolating the express-as-a-table problem from the store-data problem make each problem easier to solve.